# Calling Excel macros/Excel Solver from Python over com

Tags: python, excel, com, win32com, solver

I have a macro inside a 2007 xlsm file that, when called, creates a solver configuration (target, constraints, ...) and performs the solve without any user interaction. When run manually from Excel, this works fine.

I now want to script this from Python over com. However, when the Python code calls the solver macro:

```
app.Run("runSolver()")
```

It fails with:

> foobar.xlsm failed to solve, error message: Error in model. Please
>   verify that all cells and constraints are valid.

If I set a breakpoint in my Python environment at the call to `Run()` and then run the macro manually from Excel, it works fine, so the solver configuration can't be wrong.

The error message is listed [on the solver website](http://www.solver.com/suppstdmsgresult7.htm) but I don't think it applies as the sheet solves fine manually.

[This page suggests](http://peltiertech.com/Excel/SolverVBA.html) that the solver environment is not yet set up when calling through com.  However, adding

```
Application.Run "Solver.xla!Solver.Solver2.Auto_open"
```

As the first line of my solver macro results in the more generic:

```
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\gen_py\00020813-0000-0000-C000-000000000046x0x1x6.py", line 35061, in Run
    , Arg26, Arg27, Arg28, Arg29, Arg30
  File "c:\python26\lib\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 456, in _ApplyTypes_
        self._oleobj_.InvokeTypes(dispid, 0, wFlags, retType, argTypes, *args),
com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

So what is the right thing to do?

---

**Edit:**

I isolated it down to a reproducable test case:

Python code:

```
from win32com.client import Dispatch
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Dispatch("Excel.Application")
    app.Visible = True
    app.Workbooks.Open(r'C:\path\to\testsolver.xlsm')
    app.Run("runsolver()")
```

Excel file: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/3142953/testsolver.xlsm (you can open it with Macros disabled and inspect the simple sub in `module1` to verify it's safe).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally found a solution after posting on the [MSDN Excel Developers forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/exceldev/thread/1ebd2da3-3fe7-46ed-8872-1f7e3a6b980c).  And the solution was maddingly trivial:

Instead of running the solver like so:

```
app.Run("runsolver()")
```

You apparently have to drop the brackets and run it like so:

```
app.Run("runsolver")
```

Go figure.